# How can I determine in a FMX Stringgrid if a column is resized?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tstringgrid

How can I determine if in a `FMX Stringgrid` a column is resized?

I can't find any information about it online.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and why it didn't work!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow, and then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question.

Comment: I wonder where you have looked: [click here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Grid.TColumn.OnResize). It's right there

Comment: I Totally overlooked it I looked in Delphi at the Column, there you cannot set it in design time, only in runtime. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use the OnResize action of the column and inside do what you need - set some boolean variable like Column_resized to true, etc.